# rails 4 passing a value to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, parameter-passing

I have some radio buttons in show.erb.html and i want to pass the value of the selected one to the controller using a submit button or link_to

here is show.html.erb

```
<ol>
<% for poll_answer in @poll_question.poll_answers %>
  <li>
    <%= radio_button_tag "poll", poll_answer.content ,true%>
    <%= h poll_answer.content %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

---

and here is the controller `poll_questions_controller.rb`

```
def calc
  p = PollAnswer.find_by_content params[:poll]
  m= p.counter
  if m.nil == true
    p.update_attributes counter: 1
  else
    m = 1+m
    p.update_attributes counter: m
  end 
end
```

---

i tried link_to

```
<% link_to "click here ", controller: :poll_questions, action: :calc, :poll_questions => { :poll=> calc} %>
```

but it didn't work

Comment: use form tag or form_for helper to submit the value to controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try form_tag helper and set your path

```
    <%= form_tag calc_path do %>
      <ol>
        <% for poll_answer in @poll_question.poll_answers %>
          <li>
            <%= radio_button_tag "poll", poll_answer.content ,true%>
            <%= h poll_answer.content %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
       </ol>
      <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

In your route.rb file add the following

```
post 'calc' => 'poll_questions#calc', as: :calc
```

Comment: i am getting this error when trying your code `No route matches [POST] "/poll_questions/calc"`

Comment: i have updated my answer with route...please try above route if haven't already define.